# SQL Server EXCEPT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, except

Here's the situation I'm in.  I have a table containing peoples' information.  Some of them are imported from another system while some are imported manually.  What I would like to do is pull everyone in, but if there is a record entered manually and a record that was imported, I want to select only the imported one (since it is likely more up to date).

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work (it only returns the manually entered records):

```
SELECT --fields go here
FROM
        (
                SELECT PERSON_UID, instype
                FROM AdmitsInterfaceTable
                WHERE instype='M' --Manually entered people
            EXCEPT
                SELECT PERSON_UID, instype
                FROM AdmitsInterfaceTable
                WHERE instype='I' --Imported people
        ) P,
        AdmitsInterfaceTable A
     WHERE 
        P.PERSON_UID=A.PERSON_UID
        AND P.instype=A.instype
```

I have a feeling this isn't working because of the inner query also pulling in the instype column, but I can't think of any better ways to do this.  Any advice?

Comment: first, if a record was added manually and one was added from an import, would they have the same person_uid? If so why aren't you updating the record instead of adding it in the import? Why are you deliberately creating duplicates?
Also please start using ANSI standard joins. Your join syntax is 17 years out of date.

Comment: The data is actually persistently held elsewhere.  I'm just bringing it in to a table as a temporary staging point where a vendor system can access them and determine which records need to be updated and/or inserted.  Yeah, I can update the records in the staging area, but it's easier just to remove and then re-pull all the imported records every night.  We enter records manually very rarely, but often enough that it can cause problems if not handled carefully.

Comment: Do any of the proposed solutions help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT PERSON_UID, instype
    FROM AdmitsInterfaceTable a
    WHERE instype='I' --get all imported people            
 union -- plus all manuals who are not also imported
 SELECT PERSON_UID, instype
    FROM AdmitsInterfaceTable a
    WHERE instype='M' --Imported people
    and not exists (  -- without imported matches
     select * from FROM AdmitsInterfaceTable b
     WHERE instype='I' and b.person_uid = a.person_uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.person_UID is null THEN a.person_UID ELSE person_UID END, 
CASE WHEN b.person_UID is null THEN a.instype   ELSE instype   END
--and so forth through all the columns you want
FROM
(SELECT PERSON_UID, instype  -- add list of additional fields you need here
from AdmitsInterfaceTable  WHERE instype='M' ) A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT PERSON_UID, instype  -- add list of additional fields you need here
from AdmitsInterfaceTable  WHERE instype='I' ) B on A.PERSON_UID = B.PERSON_UID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT --fields go here
FROM AdmitsInterfaceTable A
 WHERE 
    P.PERSON_UID=A.PERSON_UID
    AND P.instype=A.instype
AND instype='M' --Manually entered people
AND person_uid not in (
SELECT PERSON_UID FROM AdmitsInterfaceTable
WHERE instype='I' --Imported people
)
```